# Design And Analysis of Algorithm : Recursive Relation

Tags: algorithm, analysis, recurrence

I have a great Doubt in solving this recursive relation. Can anyone provide me a solution?

The relation:

T(n) = Sumation i=1 to N T(i) +1...,

[image]

What is the bigOh order?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. What problems are you having in the process of solving? What approaches have you taken?

Comment: Compute the first few values by hand !

Answer (score 2):

Taking the first order difference allows you to get rid of the summation.

```
T(n) - T(n-1) = (Sum(1<=i<n: T(i)) + 1) - (Sum(1<=i<n-1: T(i)) + 1) = T(n-1)
```

Hence

```
T(n) = 2.T(n-1)
```

Comment: But the Solution suggested by others were

t(n) = t(n-1) +1 
hence order oh ...O(n)

Comment: Compute the first few values by hand !

Answer (score 0):

A recurrence relation describes a sequence of numbers. Early terms are specified explicitly and later terms are expressed as a function of their predecessors. As a trivial example, this recurrence describes the sequence 1, 2, 3, etc.:

```java
    void Sample(int n)
    {
        if (n > 0) {
            Sample(n-1);
            System.out.println('here');
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    Sample(3);
```

Here, the first term is defined to be 1 and each subsequent term is one more than its predecessor. In order to analyze a recurrence relationship, we need to know execution time of each line of code, In above example:

```java
    void Sample(int n)
    {
               if (n > 0) {
     // T(n-1)      Sample(n-1);
     // 1           System.out.println('here');
               } else {
                   return 1;
               }
    }
```

We define T(n) as a:

[image]

For solving `T(n)= T(n-1)+1`, If we know what is `T(n-1)`, then we can substitute it and get answer, Let's substitute it with `n` then, we will have:

```java
T(n-1)= T(n-1-1)+1 => T(n-2)+1
//in continue
T(n)=[T(n-2)+1]+1 => T(n-2)+2
//and again
T(n)=[T(n-3)+2]+1 => T(n-3)+3
.
.
.
// if repeat it k times, while it ends
T(n)= T(n-k)+k
```

As you see it is increasing by 1 in each step, If we go `k` times, Then `T(n)= T(n-k)+k`. Now, we need to know the smallest value(when the the function will stop, always must be a point to stop). In this problem zero is end of recursive stack. sine we assume that we go `k` times to reach zero, the solution will be:

```java
// if n-k is final step
n-k = 0 => n = k
// replace k with n
T(n)= T(n-n)+n => T(n)= T(0)+n;
// we know
T(0) = 1;
T(n) = 1+n => O(n)
```

The big `O` is `n`, It means this recursive algorithms in worst case goes `n` times.